# Chrome DevTools for node: How to stop in specific file

Tags: node.js, google-chrome, gruntjs, google-chrome-devtools

I try to debug a grunt task with Chrome DevTools on Windows using the following command

```
node --inspect-brk node_modules\grunt\bin\grunt
```

This works nicely and the Chrome debugger stops in the root grunt javascript. But of course, I do not want to debug grunt, but my own "gruntfile.js". How can I set a breakpoint into that file, as it is not loaded yet?

I tried to add my project folder in the Chrome DevTools under "FileSystem", but whatever I add there as a breakpoint does not stop.

Comment: Try to add a debugger; statement in the code

Comment: That's a good workaround.. thanks!

Comment: Thanks! Glad it worked out!